# How to align center with smaller size parent that has a 3d style

Tags: javascript, css, css-position, css-transforms, centering

My code is about Filping Card. I have 3 elements "flipperContainer" ,"flipper", "CarbBack"("CardBack" is put on page with rotateY 180 first).
I was run into problem when try to align "CardBack"'s center with flipper, when the size of "CardBack" is bigger than "flipper", it seems that "CardBack" always align left with "Flipper".
I have try many methods, using flex layout or using fixed position with "CardBack", but it just doesn't work, seems to because that its parent "flipper" has a 3d style.
Following is my code, I really need some help that can center "CardBack" with "Flipper" while maintaining all the 3d style, thanks!

```js
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

class Card extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }
   render(){
     
     return (
         <div className="flipperContainer">
           <div className="flipper">
             <div className="cardBack">
             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
     )
   }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<Card/>, root);
```

```css
.flipperContainer{
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  
  border-radius:35px;
  background-color: black;
}
.flipperContainer:hover .flipper, .flipperContainer.hover .flipper {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipper {
  width: 40px;
 height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
 -webkit-transition: 1s;
 -o-transition: 1s;
 transition: 1s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  border-radius:35px;
  right:50%;
  position:relative;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.cardBack {
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
         backface-visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
   width: 70px;
 height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nothing in your code is trying to center any element

Comment: Forgive my expression，i'm not trying to center single element，but center the child with parent（that the two elements have same midpoint horizontally and vertically ）.In my case is center "cardBack"(green) with "flipper"(red), right now they are left aligned. I have tried many methods that didnot work, so i didnot put code on. I believe it need some css tricks, because the "flipper" has a 3d style. NEED YOUR HELP, THANKS.

Comment: And there is no attempt in your code to center that element.